# Alphabetizing band names when the name includes a member's name

Tags: names, proper-nouns, alphabet

When one is alphabetizing band names which are named after a member of the band, do you put the last name first?

For a few examples, the following bands are names, but not of actual people:

> Pink Floyd -> under P
>
> Jethro Tull -> under J

And of course we have performers who record under their own name:

> Billy Joel -> Joel, Billy (J)
>
> Michael Jackson -> Jackson, Michael (J)

But what about bands whose name includes the name of a member? Like the following:

> The Alan Parsons Project
>
> Ben Harper and the Innocent Criminals
>
> Ben Fold's Five

Is it a *rule* that these should be alphabetized according to the band name (A, B, B respectively above) rather then the person's name (P, H, F respectively), or is it a convention adopted *ad hoc*?

Of course, there could be all kinds of strange variations of this - what about a band named "Herman Melville"? What about a band named "Herman Melville" who has a person named "Herman Melville" in the band? I'm not so concerned which how musicians can drive librarians crazy, but just if there *is* a rule, what is it?

Comment: Jethro Tull is the name of an actual person - he was an 18th century English agriculturalist.

Comment: I don't think there are any hard and fast rules about this, but my own personal preference is to alphabetize by the last name of the person if they are in the band and by the first letter if the band is named after some other person or the name is made up. So, Jethro Tull goes under J and Pink Floyd goes under P, but The Alan Parsons Project goes under P and Ben Folds Five goes under F.

Comment: @JohnFeltz: Smart guy! That is related to my point about Herman Melville I guess.

Comment: @AndySchweig: I understand we might have our own preferences, that's fine. I'm wondering if there is some kind of established standard I could either decide to follow or ignore.

(The argument here is the other members of the Alan Parsons Project might not appreciate being filed under "Parsons")

Comment: I doubt the other members will ever know how you chose to file them.  You might choose to see how itunes, or other online music sites handle it.

Comment: There should be a rule from filing books - something like "the Jane Smith letters" would need a place in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't have a source for you, but I feel confident that it would go like this:

Ben Fold's Five: B

Billy Joel: J

Pink Floyd: P

etc.

Comment: So you're obviously using some kind of intuition right? Which basically matches my own - but than what do you say about a band who calls themselves "Joe Biden"? Or a band, lead by Joe Biden, called "The Fantastical Musical Experience of Joe Biden"? Without a rule and parameters, I'm not sure how to extend my intuition.

Comment: By the basic rules that example would be under F for  "fantastical" - it's only when the band name starts with the member's name (excluding "the") that you have a problem. (@cduston)

Comment: If you're talking about the musician, go for the last name (unless it's a musician who goes by a first name only).  If you're talking about an ensemble/band, alphabetize just the way you would for a title of a book.  Skip things like "The" and pick out the first meaningful first letter.